# Excel PivotChart text directions of multi level label

Tags: vba, text, charts, directions

I have a PivotChart which has two row fields, so there are two level labels in x-axis. I want to change the text direction of both levels, however, it only works for the first label, not the second, as shown below:

[image]

VBA codes can be useful too. The following is for the first Label:

```
ActiveChart.Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Orientation = 90 ' degrees
```

How can I change the second level label???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the inner-most set of a multi level category axis can be controlled, either through the UI or VBA. You cannot set the orientation of the outer category. There is no UI control for that and nothing in the VBA object model.

I know it sucks. Don't shoot the messenger.